# PHP : Retrieving keys using openssl

Tags: php, openssl

I manage to generate private / public keys using the following script :

```
$res = openssl_pkey_new(array('private_key_bits' => 2048,'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA));
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkey);
file_put_contents('test.private.key', $privkey);
$pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubkey = $pubkey["key"];
file_put_contents('test.public.key', $pubkey);
```

The generated files :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwQ5L0JQ2G5zGhC4uDISo
6krN/mKrBuULYhrVL9Zdve+C9DuH6uDTRCC07PvIKcHVj13vKB4YvRlwCCAxHg5p
34P3W9vjmrI91rdVJ31noRvJ/i5ZjNBfy7c8NrIOA6m4gicfPbozuQU741jLSncd
QuyZRrADbFWppIz/mLm5WDZk6+NUyAM2o0jvDsKE7i3sT+IKJpjUC8mE+RONIooN
tHB3GJarsCKg5L6e0EaGXlVp9MezlSSn/Z5p1Wu3GJq02lNGLT5BVgCfE7ajBDZW
RDG+Mbp4/YCt/zXz5XWm2/BxD78c2wH3qMs/bIjvq5MTta4E2VQTSCxI5fMjRUf5
QQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Could someone tell me how to retrieve my keys, in order to encrypt / decrypt files. I'm trying the following :

```
$privkey = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://test.private.key')
$pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_public('file://test.public.key')
```

But these functions return false...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry forget about this post, I just tried to make it hard where it's very simple : A file_get_contents('test.public.key') is enough to retrieve the keys ;)